# Kaltura Adding new APIs to Kaltura CE

Tags: kaltura

I am very new to Kaltura CE and want to understand different technologies used in Kaltura CE, I have Kaltura Single Server setup and able to use it. In case if I want to do any modification to APIs or add any new APIs, what all things I need to do?

For that I want to understand is all technologies that are used in Kaltura, I know there will be lot of technologies involved but a rough idea will help. Like for server side is in PHP/Java, interaction with DB using XYZ etc.

And also how to add modify kaltura APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Kaltura server is based on the LAMP stack, so PHP and mysql are the main answer to your question.
Why do you need to extend the API? not sure if it's a good idea. Maybe create your own set of API.
FYI:
the client are generated (automatically) in /opt/kaltura/app/clients/
so for php5 you can add a plugin under  /opt/kaltura/app/clients/php5/KalturaPlugins/
But it may be overrun if you upgrade the server

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am trying to create my own set of new APIs. From your answer what does it mean by `clients are generated in /opt/kaltura/app/clients/`  are you talking about the client SDK that a person uses to communicate with kaltura server like Android, JS, PHP SDK, but we need to have that (new) API related functionality supported on the server side as well right? so how to do that, and regarding plugin is it that we need to add php5 plugin to add new API to kaltura server.  Got your point that it will overrun new API when server is updated, so we are stuck with one version.

Comment: The code for the server side is in /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3, and of course you will need to add the code for yourself too.  The generator of client is in   /opt/kaltura/app/generator, and again you can create something for yourself if you really need it. But I think a different API/one that extends kaltura is better

Comment: Yes I am targeting something smiler, Where the existing API of kaltura will provide some more custom information. so i have to modify code in api_v3 folder to extend the exsting API and then generate client libs to use it right?